# Python printing on same line for multiple line values

Tags: python

I have a question about printing on same line.

I'm trying to do the following:

[image: sample output of ascii formatting]

and the code i wrote is below

```
dic = {'1':'#\n#\n#\n#\n#',
       '2':'###\n  #\n###\n#\n###',
       '3':'###\n  #\n###\n  #\n###',
       '4':'# #\n# #\n###\n  #\n  #',
       '5':'###\n#\n###\n  #\n###',
       '6':'###\n#\n###\n# #\n###',
       '7':'###\n  #\n  #\n  #\n  #',
       '8':'###\n# #\n###\n# #\n###',
       '9':'###\n# #\n###\n  #\n###',
       '0':'###\n# #\n# #\n# #\n###'
}

value = input("Enter an integer: ")

value = str(value)

for chr in value:
    print(dic[chr], sep=' ')
```

but with my code when i run it, it prints in separate lines

[image]

could you please help how to print on same line.

or if my code is incorrect, could you please advise on how to write it correctly?

thank you in advance!

Comment: The point of that exercise is to print the first line of each desired figure, then the second line of each, and so on.

Comment: You'd need to concatenate each line of each number individually, or resort to something like ncurses. You can't just print them in order like this since once you've printed the first number, you've emitted newlines, and will start printing at the bottom where they left off.

Comment: each line is different for different combinations of numbers. You could for example have the numbers in the dictionary encoded rotated 90 degrees clockwise, and then add them all to a block of text and rotate that block counter-clockwise before printing the final output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write a function `combine` that combines two strings into one line, by splitting both strings on a newline, finding the longest section of the first string, then using that to determine the padding:

```py
def combine(a, b):
    a_lines = a.split("\n")
    b_lines = b.split("\n")
    padding = max(len(line) for line in a_lines)
    return "\n".join(a_line.ljust(padding) + " " + b_line for a_line, b_line in zip(a_lines, b_lines))
```

Then, just use it:

```py
dic = {'1':'#\n#\n#\n#\n#',
       '2':'###\n  #\n###\n#\n###',
       '3':'###\n  #\n###\n  #\n###',
       '4':'# #\n# #\n###\n  #\n  #',
       '5':'###\n#\n###\n  #\n###',
       '6':'###\n#\n###\n# #\n###',
       '7':'###\n  #\n  #\n  #\n  #',
       '8':'###\n# #\n###\n# #\n###',
       '9':'###\n# #\n###\n  #\n###',
       '0':'###\n# #\n# #\n# #\n###'
}

value = input("Enter an integer: ")

value = str(value)

output = ""
for chr in value:
    if output:
        output = combine(output, dic[chr])
    else:
        # don't combine with nothing
        output = dic[chr]

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect. You need to join the first line of each digit, then the second line, etc.

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to get the lines of the digits together, though to accommodate that, you'll need to transform `dic` so that each digit is in separate units for each line, like this:

```
{k: v.splitlines() for k, v in dic.items()}
```

You'll also need to fix the spacing so that each unit has a constant width.

Once that's done, get the digits together, zip, and print:

```
value = input("Enter an integer: ")

digits = [dic[c] for c in value]
for line in zip(*digits):
    print(*line)
```

This uses the [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) operator (AKA "splat").

BTW, `str(input())` is redundant since `input()` returns a string.